# UIAlertController is transparent on iPhone 5s/s 8.4 and crashes on iPhone 5s/s 9.3

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, ios9.3, ios8.4

Can any one have any idea about this. I have a simple code which is not working properly. UIAlertController is  transparent on iPhone 5s/s 8.4 and it crashes on iPhone 5s/s 9.3. Code below:

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message:"message" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Crash Message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIAlertController is expected to have a visual style during transitioning'

Comment: I'm also getting this error.  Do you manage multiple UIWindow instances in your App?